# How to debug Fiware-Orion

Tags: c++, fiware, fiware-orion

I'm new to this field.

I've installed Fiware-orion via **source** on my VM (centOS), by following the link below: 
`https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/admin/build_source/index.html`.
Currently I'm working on a Fiware-Orion issue, but I don't know how to debug Fiware-Orion. I've searched on google and Official documentation of Fiware-Orion but I don't find any relative documentation/material related to Fiware-Orion debugging.

I've find some commands related to Orion debugging (but I don't know whether these commands are correct or not) and I'm following these commands:

-> First installed orion from source and mongoDB then,

1. make di
2. `./BUILD_DEBUG/src/app/contextBroker/contextBroker -port 1026`
3. `curl localhost:1026/version`
4. gdb `./BUILD_DEBUG/src/app/contextBroker/contextBroker -tui`
5. b (lineNo)
6. run

   `[root@localhost fiware-orion]# gdb ./BUILD_DEBUG/src/app/contextBroker/contextBroker`

   ```
   GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.6.1-100.el7
   Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
   This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
   There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
   and "show warranty" for details.
   This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
   For bug reporting instructions, please see:
   <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
   Reading symbols from /root/workingDir/fiware-orion/BUILD_DEBUG/src/app/contextBroker/contextBroker...done.

   (gdb) b 101
   Breakpoint 1 at 0x6033c9: file /root/workingDir/fiware-orion/src/app/contextBroker/contextBroker.cpp, line 101.

   (gdb) run
   Starting program: /root/workingDir/fiware-orion/./BUILD_DEBUG/src/app/contextBroker/contextBroker
   [Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
   Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".

   Breakpoint 1, fileExists (path=0xbfc380 <pidPath> "/tmp/contextBroker.pid")
       at /root/workingDir/fiware-orion/src/app/contextBroker/contextBroker.cpp:371
   371       if (access(path, F_OK) == 0)
   Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install boost-filesystem-1.53.0-27.el7.x86_64 boost-regex-1.53.0-27.el7.x86_64 boost-system-1.53.0-27.el7.x86_64 boost-thread-1.53.0-27.el7.x86_64 cyrus-sasl-lib-2.1.26-23.el7.x86_64 glibc-2.17-292.el7.x86_64 gmp-6.0.0-15.el7.x86_64 gnutls-3.3.29-9.el7_6.x86_64 keyutils-libs-1.5.8-3.el7.x86_64 krb5-libs-1.15.1-37.el7_7.2.x86_64 libcom_err-1.42.9-16.el7.x86_64 libcurl-7.29.0-54.el7_7.1.x86_64 libffi-3.0.13-18.el7.x86_64 libgcc-4.8.5-39.el7.x86_64 libgcrypt-1.5.3-14.el7.x86_64 libgpg-error-1.12-3.el7.x86_64 libicu-50.1.2-15.el7.x86_64 libidn-1.28-4.el7.x86_64 libselinux-2.5-14.1.el7.x86_64 libssh2-1.8.0-3.el7.x86_64 libstdc++-4.8.5-39.el7.x86_64 libtasn1-4.10-1.el7.x86_64 libuuid-2.23.2-61.el7_7.1.x86_64 nettle-2.7.1-8.el7.x86_64 nspr-4.21.0-1.el7.x86_64 nss-3.44.0-7.el7_7.x86_64 nss-softokn-freebl-3.44.0-8.el7_7.x86_64 nss-util-3.44.0-4.el7_7.x86_64 openldap-2.4.44-5.el7.x86_64 openssl-libs-1.0.2k-19.el7.x86_64 p11-kit-0.23.5-3.el7.x86_64 pcre-8.32-17.el7.x86_64 zlib-1.2.7-18.el7.x86_64

   (gdb) list
   366     *
   367     * fileExists -
   368     */
   369     static bool fileExists(char* path)
   370     {
   371       if (access(path, F_OK) == 0)
   372       {
   373         return true;
   374       }
   375

   (gdb) n
   376       return false;
   (gdb) n
   377     }
   (gdb) n
   pidFile (justCheck=true) at /root/workingDir/fiware-orion/src/app/contextBroker/contextBroker.cpp:397
   397       if (justCheck == true)
   (gdb) print justCheck
   $1 = true
   (gdb) list
   876         {
   877           LM_X(1, ("Fatal Error (when option '-https' is used, option '-cert' is mandatory)"));
   878         }
   879       }
   880
   881       notificationModeParse(notificationMode, &notificationQueueSize, &notificationThreadNum); // This should be called before contextBrokerInit()
   882       LM_T(LmtNotifier, ("notification mode: '%s', queue size: %d, num threads %d", notificationMode, notificationQueueSize, notificationThreadNum));
   883       LM_I(("Orion Context Broker is running"));
   884
   885       if (fg == false)
   (gdb) n
   882       LM_T(LmtNotifier, ("notification mode: '%s', queue size: %d, num threads %d", notificationMode, notificationQueueSize, notificationThreadNum));
   (gdb) step
   883       LM_I(("Orion Context Broker is running"));
   (gdb)
   ```

**While I'm using skip(i.e. 's') command to enter into the function but it moves to the next line. I don't know where I'm making mistakes.**

**Actually I wanted to debug the files present inside `https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/blob/master/src/lib/` folders but I'm not able to reach there. Even, I'm not able to move out of `fiware-orion/src/app/contextBroker/contextBroker.cpp` class.**

Can anyone suggest me correct commands for debugging Fiware-Orion, or tell me where I'm making mistakes, please.

Is there any proper documentation available regarding to debugging the Fiware-Orion?

Comment: Skip step 2. With your current "method" you are dirst starting a broker running outside of gdb and after that you try to start another broker inside gdb. Both using the same port., and the same pid.file. This is not possible. It IS possible to run two instances of the broker in the same machine, but that's not what you want. Simply skip step 2

Comment: Thank you for the response.
I'm able to run the commands.
But as I mentioned in the question, I wanted to debug the files present inside 'fiware-orion/src/lib/' folders.
While I'm putting next breakpoint in another file i.e. present in 'fiware-orion/src/lib/' then I get:

`(gdb) b /root/wornkingDir/fiware-orion/src/lib/mongoBackend/MongoGlobal.cpp:1107`
 `No source file named /root/wornkingDir/fiware-orion/src/lib/mongoBackend/MongoGlobal.cpp.`
 `Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or n)`

How should I proceed to debug the files present at 'fiware-orion/src/lib'.

Answer (score 1):

To debug Orion you would need it compiled in DEBUG mode. The release that you have installed is not. To get a debuggable Orion, you'll have to build it from source, and compile it for debugging.

To build Orion from sources, check out the documentation here: https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/blob/master/doc/manuals/admin/build_source.md.

Build Orion using the make target "di", which stands for "debug install".

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for response:)
I've installed orion by source and I've compiled it in debug mode too.
I've modified my question by elaborating the same. Please suggest me solution based on modified question. 
Thank you:)

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to increase the debug level of Orion itself, the command line arguments are simply:

```sh
orion -logLevel DEBUG -t 0-255 -noCache -logForHumans
```

For example, when using a Dockerized Orion, the following `docker-compose` could be used:

```yaml
  orion:
    image: fiware/orion:${ORION_VERSION}
    hostname: orion
    container_name: fiware-orion
    depends_on:
      - mongo-db
    networks:
      - default
    expose:
      - "${ORION_PORT}"
    ports:
      - "${ORION_PORT}:${ORION_PORT}" # localhost:1026
    command: -dbhost mongo-db -logLevel DEBUG -noCache -logForHumans
    healthcheck:
      test: curl --fail -s http://orion:${ORION_PORT}/version || exit 1
```

Comment: thanks for response:)
I've installed orion by source and I'm not using Dockerized Orion. 
I've modified my question by elaborating the same. Please suggest me any solution based on modified question. 
Thank you:)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I use QtCreator as IDE (in particular, [version 3.5.1](https://www.qt.io/blog/2015/10/15/qt-creator-3-5-1-released), a bit old but it works :). QtCreator integrates nicely with gdb, so it is easy to run Orion in debug mode, set breakpoints in the graphical code editor, then stimulate Orion with requests and see how it goes (breakpoint reached, etc.).